# MySQL connection using JDBC - How should I handle exceptions?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to create a method to connect to MySQL database and get some results back. Here is the code:

```
public class DepartmentDAO {

/**
 * Default constructor
 */
public DepartmentDAO() {  }

public List<Department> getDepartments() throws Exception {

    String errorMessage = "";
    DB database = new DB();
    try {
    database.open();
    Connection con = database.getConnection();}
    catch (Exception ex){
        errorMessage = "Failed to connect to Database.";}


    List <Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>();

    PreparedStatement stmt4 = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql4 = "SELECT * FROM departments_ex3_8090101;";
    try {
        stmt4 = con.prepareStatement(sql4); //initialize stmt4
        rs = stmt4.executeQuery(); //execute (SQL Statement) sql4
        while (rs.next()){
            //get ID
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            //get Name
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            //create new Department Object
            Department dep = new Department (id, name);
            //add to <Department> List
            departments.add(dep);

        }
        stmt4.close(); //close Statement stmt4
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        errorMessage = "Failed to execute query.";
    }

database.close();

} //End of getDepartments
```

Of course, due to the `Connection` object being in a try-catch block, I get errors as it is out of scope when it has to be used by my `PreparedStatement`.

Despite that, I want there to be multiple try-catch blocks in order to get the correct error message. How should I proceed in order to handle each exception separately and at the same time not get those errors?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the error message anyway, so why do you care? The best way would be to NOT catch the exception. Or at least to catch it, but to throw a different one, chaining the original SQLException to not lose the original cause of the problem. Anf to use try-with-resources to make sure your connection, statement and reultset are closed.

Comment: @JBNizet it is  used by a jsp errorpage in my application :)

Comment: No, it's not, since it's a local variable of your method, that is not returned.

Comment: Nest the try-catch blocks, and use how to learn try-with-resources.